# Sending a message based on user reaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am wanting my bot to send a message based on the reaction to user adds.

I have the code

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def testhelp(self, ctx):
    try:
        Help = discord.Embed(title="Commands and Usage", description="Choose a catagory by adding a reaction", color=0x0072ff)
        Help.add_field(name='General Commands', value='')
        Help.add_field(name='Fun Commands', value='')
        Help.add_field(name='Math Commands', value='✏')
        Help.add_field(name='Anime Commands', value='')
        Help.add_field(name='NSFW Commands', value='')
        Help.add_field(name='Music Commands', value='')
        Help.add_field(name='Mod Commands', value='')
        Help.add_field(name='Admin Commands', value='⚒')
        Help.add_field(name='Owner Commands', value='⚙')
        message = await self.client.say(embed=Help)
        await self.client.add_reaction(message, emoji='')
        await self.client.add_reaction(message, emoji='')
        await self.client.add_reaction(message, emoji='✏')
        await self.client.add_reaction(message, emoji='')
        await self.client.add_reaction(message, emoji='')
        await self.client.add_reaction(message, emoji='')
        await self.client.add_reaction(message, emoji='')
        await self.client.add_reaction(message, emoji='⚒')
        await self.client.add_reaction(message, emoji='⚙')
    except Exception as error:
        await self.client.say('{}'.format(error))
```

which works fine, I just need to figure out how to send a different message when they add a reaction listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a dictionary of emoji to responses, then check their reaction against that dictionary.  Below I use [`Client.wait_for_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for_reaction) to only process reactions that we know about from the person who invoked the command.

```
responses = {'': 'General Commands',
             '': 'Fun Commands'
             '✏': 'Math Commands',
             '': 'Anime Commands'}

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def testhelp(self, ctx):
    Help = discord.Embed(title="Commands and Usage", description="Choose a catagory by adding a reaction", color=0x0072ff)
    for emoji, name in responses.items():
        Help.add_field(name=name, value=emoji)
    message = await self.client.say(embed=Help)
    for emoji in responses:
        await self.client.add_reaction(message, emoji=emoji)
    res = await self.client.wait_for_reaction(list(responses), user=ctx.message.author)
    await self.client.say("{} you chose {}".format(res.user.mention, responses[res.reaction.emoji]))
```

If you want a more meaningful message to be sent in reply, you can write coroutines that take contexts and send the messages.

```
responses = {'': 'General Commands',
             '': 'Fun Commands'
             '✏': 'Math Commands',
             '': 'Anime Commands'}

async def general_commands(self, ctx):
    embed = ...
    await self.client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=embed)

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def testhelp(self, ctx):
    Help = discord.Embed(title="Commands and Usage", description="Choose a catagory by adding a reaction", color=0x0072ff)
    for emoji, name in responses.items():
        Help.add_field(name=name, value=emoji)
    message = await self.client.say(embed=Help)
    for emoji in responses:
        await self.client.add_reaction(message, emoji=emoji)
    res = await self.client.wait_for_reaction(list(responses), user=ctx.message.author)
    coro = getattr(self, responses[res.reaction.emoji].lower().replace(' ', '_'))
    await coro(ctx)
```

Comment: I am getting this error now 'generator' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: @DamianBenton Oops, we need to `await` `wait_for_reaction`.  I've fixed it above.

Comment: How would I make it so if they choose the reaction that is for General Commands it will send another embed message with the General help commands embed?